# How to compute the following integral using complex analysis?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

I'm trying to compute the following integral using complex analysis:
\begin{equation}
\int_0^{2\pi}\sin(\exp(e^{i \theta}))d\theta
\end{equation}
I know that there has to be an easy way out, but I can't see it.

I've tried the following: by changing of variable $z = e^{i\theta}$, we get to
\begin{equation}
\int_{|z|=1}\frac{\sin(\exp(z))}{iz}dz = \operatorname{Res}(f,0) = \lim_{|z|\to0}-i\sin(\exp(z)) = -i\sin(1)
\end{equation}
It doesn't seem right, though. Can anyone please help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\int_{|z|=1} \frac{\sin(\exp(z))}{iz}\mathrm{d}z = 2\pi i\text{ Res}\left(\frac{\sin(\exp(z))}{iz}, 0\right) = 2\pi \lim_{z\to 0} \sin(\exp(z)) = 2\pi \sin(1)$$

Comment: Oh, so I just forgot to add the $2\pi i$. Wonderful! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

In general for a holomorphic function $f$ on a disc say ($D(a,R)$) (and even for a much more class of functions), we have for every $0<r<R$:
$$
\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} f(a+re^{it})dt=f(a).  
$$
This is called the mean propriety, and the proof is direct using Cauchy formula, in fact
\begin{eqnarray}
f(a)&=&\frac{1}{2i\pi}\int_{|z-a|=r}\frac{f(z)}{z -a}dz\\
&=&\frac{1}{2i\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{f(a+re^{it})}{re^{it}}ire^{it}dt  \qquad (z=a+re^{it}) \\
&=& \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} f(a+re^{it})dt.
\end{eqnarray}

In your case, taking $f(z)=\sin(e^z)$ this function is entire (holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}$).

$$
\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} \sin(\exp(e^{it}))dt=f(0)=\sin(1).  
$$

Comment: This one is quite interesting, thanks for answering!

Answer (score 2):

You can just use power series, since both $\sin$ and $\exp$ are entire functions.
$$ \sin(\exp(e^{i\theta})) = \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}\exp((2n+1)e^{i\theta})=\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}\sum_{m\geq 0}\frac{(2n+1)^m e^{m i\theta}}{m!}\tag{1} $$
but $\int_{0}^{2\pi}e^{mi\theta}\,d\theta = 0$ unless $m=0$, so

$$ \int_{0}^{2\pi}\sin(\exp(e^{i\theta}))\,d\theta = 2\pi\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}=\color{red}{2\pi\sin(1)}. \tag{2}$$

Comment: Wow, even with power series. This was really beautiful. Thanks for replying!